# passing a second parameter in a batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a file `hello.bat` with the following code:

```
echo first: %1 and second: %2 > me.txt
```

I am trying to call this using powershell. When I pass the first parameter it works well:

```
 start-process hello test
```

However when i try to pass the second parameter like this:

```
 start-process hello test test2
```

I get this error:

> Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'test2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just try pass the arguments using a comma like this:

```
start-process hello test,test2
```

or

```
start-process hello "test test2"
```

If you want to know more you can read the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-5.1).

Comment: works great. Any idea how to pass a parameter with a space? i tried `"test 'test 2' "` it takes the second parameter as `test` not `test 2`

Comment: yes, you can do it like that `start-process hello "test","test 2"`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're starting a command line from a command line but I think this should work:

```
Start-Process -FilePath $env:ComSpec -ArgumentList "/c hello.bat test test2"
```

Don't you think it's time to replace cmd with Powershell?

You might change your bat file as well:

```
echo %1 > me.txt
echo %2 >> me.txt
```

Comment: I did try powershell first. I created ps1 files and tried running them in a couple of ways, but it kept giving me "not recognized" errors. This command finally worked with at least with one parameter

Comment: by the way your code isn't working. no errors. A window pops up and disappears. no changes to the txt file

Comment: So you might start your research a little more "bottom". What do you actually try to achieve?

Comment: ... added a proper bat file in my answer. It works this way for me.

Comment: Is the name `hallo.bat` <=> `hello.bat` the issue?

Comment: oh ... thanks for the correction. jFYI - it's the German way to say "hello". ;-)  Corrected it.