# pass parameters with space in batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, parameter-passing

Let's say I have a batch file named `hello.bat` that takes two parameters.

According to the answer here: [passing a second parameter in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48271978/passing-a-second-parameter-in-a-batch-file), I can use the following to pass two parameters using powershell:

```
start-process hello "test test2"
```

Now, considering that the two parameters are separated by space, how would I pass a parameter with a space. For instance what if the first parameter was `test one` instead of `test`? I have tried `start-process hello "test","test 2"`, does not seem to work.

Comment: Did you try, `start-process hello """test one"",test2"`

Comment: i did now. works perfectly. could you post it as the answer so i can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding double doublequotes like this:

```ps1
start-process hello """test one"",test2"
```

*Hope this helped you out!*